# How can I put the input inside a string which already exist?

Tags: python

I have a string called data, you can see below. I just want to take an input from user and put the input inside ability_id field in data.

```
def main():
    ability_id = input("Enter an ability id) # example:abc-123-abc-123
    data = '{"paw":"1234","ability_id": f"{ability_id}" ,"obfuscator":"plain-text"}'
    print(data)
```

Comment: Could you have data as a dict, and just convert it to string at the end? i.e. str(data)?

Comment: Why do you need to make `data` into a string? What are you going to do with it?

Comment: @afterburner Yeah actually I can do that as you said but I just wonder that if I can do it as a string or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't think, saving the string like this has a lot of sense, I will still give you an answer to your question.
If you want to do it like this you can, as you already nearly did, use the f-string.
But you can't just simply start an f-string inside a normal string - this is not, how this works. Instead, you have to make the whole thing an f-string and then indicate inside this string, where you want to place the variable. Something like this:

`data = f'{{"paw":"1234","ability_id": "{ability_id}" ,"obfuscator":"plain-text"}}'`

Attention: Watch out, that you use the double curly-brackets at the beginning and ending of the string, otherwise it will not work